# Is there any significance with the default values for the NUMBER datatype of an Oracle database's metadata?

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, eclipse-plugin, xtext

I have a question regarding the newer versions of the Oracle jdbc drivers. When creating a table you have the option to define its column datatype as NUMBER, which is essentially a float value correct?

If this is the case then why does the metadata (with newer drivers) return as -127 for DECIMAL_DIGITS and 0 as COLUMN_SIZE (through SQuirreL at least):
[image: Default returned values for a NUMBER column]

Do these values mean anything or can I assume that they are actually DECIMAL_DIGITS 127 and COLUMN_SIZE 38 (the maximum values allowed in the NUMBER datatype https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm) or is there some reason to why the values are set like this?  I couldn't find any documentation to why or when this change was made to Oracle's jdbc driver.

If it will help in anyway, the issue that I am having is that after fetching the metadata from the database, I would like to save the data with eclipse's xtext and it throws a fit when the values are negative it seems.  I am very new to xtext and not sure if this is configurable or working as intended.

Comment: what is the version of your JDBC driver?

Comment: @wero my JDBC driver's version is 11.2.0.4.0 (according to the driver's manifest.mf).  I believe its the newest one off their site.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a driver issue.

The JDBC driver upgrade from 11.2.0.2 to 11.2.0.4 [stated](http://download.oracle.com/otn/utilities_drivers/jdbc/112/Readme.txt%20List%20of%20Fixes%20in%2011.2.0.4) that it fixed a similar issue for INTEGERs:

> 12775220 DatabaseMetaData.getColumns() returns unexpected values in
>   COLUMN_SIZE and DECIMAL_DIGITS for INTEGER columns

However the problem still seems to be there. Here is solution found by Rod Allen on the [oracle forums](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3677876?start=0&tstart=0):

> Add the JVM argument `-Doracle.jdbc.J2EE13Compliant=true`.

Maybe it also solves your NUMBER problem. Else I would recommend to file a bug report.

**Update:**

Tested the hypothesis and the fix using the JVM argument works on my machine. The NUMBER field is now reported having COLUMN_SIZE 38 and DECIMAL_DIGITS 0.
Fields defined as NUMBER(n,m) do not suffer from the problem with or without the JVM argument.

Comment: @wmgeiger101x seems to work, to test start squirrel with the JVM argument.

Comment: so this is just a work around correct? The bug is still in the current driver for the NUMBER datatype?